# How to make a JSON String?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have the following example where I get a Exception parsing my Json Data:

```
String s = "{\n" +
        "\t\"foo1\": {\n" +
        "\t\t\"array1\": [\n" +
        "\t\t\t[1, \"One\"],\n" +
        "\t\t\t[2, \"Two\"],\n" +
        "\t\t\t[3, \"Three\"]\n" +
        "\t\t]\n" +
        "\t}\n" +
        "}";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s); // Exception because the file could not be parsed
```

This is just an example. Normally I read the String out of a JSON file but the content of my string is the same.

In the real example I do:

```
InputStream inputStream = assets.open(path);

int size = inputStream.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
inputStream.read(buffer);
inputStream.close();

String s = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
```

What I need to change to get my JSON parsed?

**EDIT:**
The error is: `cannot evaluate org.json.jsonobject.tostring()`

Comment: JSON parsed to an object? You can have a look at this library. https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: What's the exception ? Did you try to remove the useless \t and \n ?

Comment: try using a site like this https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to validate your json string before using it in your java code

Comment: Post the actual error message, not your paraphrase of it.

Comment: JSONObject newobject = new JSONObject();
    

       newobject.put(s);
      
       
       JSONObject finaldata = new JSONObject();
       finaldata.put("NewRequest", newobject);

Comment: As others said, please post the error message. Your posted JSON is perfectly valid for Groovy `JsonSlurper` e. g.

Answer (score 1):

Example where you mentioned I tried running in my system I able parse it properly:

```
String s = "{\n" +
                "\t\"foo1\": {\n" +
                "\t\t\"array1\": [\n" +
                "\t\t\t[1, \"One\"],\n" +
                "\t\t\t[2, \"Two\"],\n" +
                "\t\t\t[3, \"Three\"]\n" +
                "\t\t]\n" +
                "\t}\n" +
                "}";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONObject foo1 = jsonObject.optJSONObject("foo1");
                    JSONArray array1 = foo1.optJSONArray("array1");
                        for (int i=0;i<array1.length();i++){
                            JSONArray list=array1.getJSONArray(i);
                            Log.e("out put "+i,list.optString(0) +":"+list.optString(1));
                        }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Output:

```
 output 0: 1:One
 output 1: 2:Two
 output 2: 3:Three
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Gson to create Json string from Java object.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

String json = gson.toJson(myObject); // myObject - instance of MyObject
```

Comment: I'd recommend Jackson over gson.

Comment: I know I can; I prefer the other.  Used by Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "[\n" +
    "\t\t\t[1, \"One\"],\n" +
    "\t\t\t[2, \"Two\"],\n" +
    "\t\t\t[3, \"Three\"]\n" +
    "\t\t]\n" +
    "\t}\n" +
    "}";

JSONObject array1 = new JSONObject();
array1.put(s);
JSONObject foo1 = new JSONObject(); 
finaldata.put("array1", array1);
```

Comment: Kindly modify the string 's' a bit

Comment: You should edit this answer to add some explanation of what this does and how it solves the problem.